# React not getting image from backend. Nodejs multer-s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, multer

Im building a blog mern app and i switched to multer-s3 to upload images. The issue i have is that react keeps throwing undefined when trying to upload an image from a backend endpoint. In the backend im using multer-s3 and in the frontend reactjs and nothing seems to work.
.
React code

```
const handleImage = async()=>{
        try {
            console.log(pic)
            var datta = new FormData();

            if (pic) datta.append("pics", pic)
            
            const {data} = await axios.post("/upload",{pic})
            setPic(data)
            console.log("data " + data)
            console.log(pic)
            console.log("formdara" + datta)
    
        } catch (error) {
            toast({
                title:"an error happened",
                description:error.message,
                position:"bottom",
                isClosable:true,
                duration:5000
            })
        }
        
        }
```

nodejs route

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
//   if(req.file) {
//     data.image = req.file.location
// }
res.json(req.file)
});
```

nodejs multer-s3 helper

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const path = require("path")

const s3 = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY, // store it in .env file to keep it safe
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
    },
    region: "sa-east-1" // this is the region that you select in AWS account
})


const s3Storage = multerS3({
    s3: s3, // s3 instance
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET, // change it as per your project requirement
    acl: "public-read", // storage access type
    metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, {fieldname: file.fieldname})
    },
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = Date.now() + "_" + file.fieldname + "_" + file.originalname;
        cb(null, fileName);
    }
});


function sanitizeFile(file, cb) {
    // Define the allowed extension
    const fileExts = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif"];

    // Check allowed extensions
    const isAllowedExt = fileExts.includes(
        path.extname(file.originalname.toLowerCase())
    );

    // Mime type must be an image
    const isAllowedMimeType = file.mimetype.startsWith("image/");

    if (isAllowedExt && isAllowedMimeType) {
        return cb(null, true); // no errors
    } else {
        // pass error msg to callback, which can be displaye in frontend
        cb("Error: File type not allowed!");
    }
}

// our middleware
const uploadImage = multer({
    storage: s3Storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        sanitizeFile(file, callback)
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 // 2mb file size
    }
})

module.exports = uploadImage;
```

i want to be able to upload in my frontend an image, using the backend endpoint.